# Equivalent of objcopy -0 binary for Mach-O object files in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, file-conversion, binary

Equivalent of `objcopy -O binary <FILE> <FILE>.bin` for Mach-O object files in macOS?

I want to dump the executable code in the `__TEXT` segment to a flat binary file on macOS.

This can be accomplished on Linux as follows:

`objcopy -O binary <FILE> <FILE>.bin`, where `<FILE>` would be an ELF file.

However, since `objcopy` isn't available (or very poorly supported) on macOS (e.g. `llvm-objcopy` cannot handle Mach-O objects), how can I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

I do that using a small Python script, included below:

```
import sys
from macholib.MachO import MachO
m = MachO(sys.argv[1])
__TEXT = (cmd for load_cmd, cmd, data in m.headers[0].commands
          if getattr(cmd, 'segname', '').rstrip('\0') == '__TEXT').next()
print '__TEXT segment: offset %x size %x' % (__TEXT.fileoff, __TEXT.filesize)
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
f.seek(__TEXT.fileoff)
open('__TEXT.bin', 'wb').write(f.read(__TEXT.filesize))
```

Save that code to a file named "extract.py" and run it like this:

```
python extract.py AppName
```

where AppName is the name of the file that holds the application program.

The program will generate a file called __TEXT.bin that holds the contents of the __TEXT segment (i.e. the executable code).